# java.lang.ClassFormatError: Incompatible magic value 218774561

Tags: java, class, jar, applet, classformaterror

Hey everyone I am making my first applet for java today. I have been using a subdomain at a server and I don't know what to do because I am getting this really weird error.

I have my jar in the server and everything but every time I try to load the Applet this happens.

> java.lang.ClassFormatError: Incompatible magic value 218774561 in class file Evolution/EvolutionApplet

Upon research it appears that an incompatible magic value means that something has been corrupted in the .jar

Here is the website http://dementedgames.site88.net/Main.html
the jars name is Evolution if you need the html code it is at the website.

Edit: The applet should be launched from Evolution.EvolutionApplet not Evolution.Evolution

Comment: How are you creating your jar?

Comment: Great question.  Shows research effort, and links to a failing example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The original problem seems fixed now.  I could download the Jar from http://dementedgames.site88.net/Evolution.jar

### Update

It seems the `Evolution.Evolution` class is not an applet! Running it from the command line using:

```
java -jar Evolution.jar
```

Produces a frame (with a very 'retro' look)!  As such, forget this applet nonsense, and **launch the frame from a link using [Java Web Start](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/java-web-start/info).**

### Old Answer

OTOH it now throws a `ClassNotFoundException` that (after inspecting the Jar) makes me think it should be:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Evolution</title>
</head>
<body bgcolor="#000000" text="#906060">
<center>
<applet code="Evolution.Evolution" archive="Evolution.jar" width="800" height="600">
</applet>
</center>
</body>
</html>
```

There are two changes to the `code` attribute worth noting.

1. The `.class` extension was removed.  A minor matter, adding it is tolerated, but not correct.
2. The `Applet` removed from the class name.

Answer (score 14):

The [magic value](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_(programming)) of a valid Java class is `0xCAFEBABE`, which is the hex value of `3405691582`. This is represented by the first 4 bytes of the file. But you're getting `218774561` which in turn stands for the ASCII characters `CR`, `LF`, `<` and `!` (the CRLF is a newline). To see it yourself, run this piece of code:

```
int magic = 218774561;
ByteBuffer b = ByteBuffer.allocate(4);
b.putInt(magic);
System.out.println(new String(b.array()));
```

This in combination with the applet being served by a website suggests that it's the start of a `<!DOCTYPE>` which in turn suggests that it's a HTML document.

So, the request to `Evolution.jar` has apparently *actually* returned a HTML document. You should be able to see it yourself when you change the current request URI in browser address bar to point to applet's URL (e.g. change `/page.html` in end of URL to `/Evolution.jar`). Then you'll see what the browser *actually* retrieved when it tried to download the applet. Perhaps it's a simple HTTP 404 error document.

To fix it, just make sure that the URL in the `archive` attribute is correct. It's relative to the current request URL as you see in browser address bar.

Answer (score 0):

BalusC above has explained it really well. In addition to that you can check this link
[Thread: Incompatible magic value 218774561 error in applet](https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=2222635)

It seems that the codebase and/or the code attribute of ur applet tag need to pointed properly.