# Open Applet twice

Tags: java, applet, nullpointerexception

My applet run when I open my web application and works fine. Inside this web application, I have a button, that if my user click in this button, the applet will open in a pop up, and load the sames .dll files.

A got the error that the .dll files was loaded in another classloader, and googling it, I saw that I can't load the .dll again. So I cut the `<archive>` tag in my `<applet>` like this

```
<applet code="com.griaule.fingerprintsdk.appletsample.FormMain" height="550" width="550">
        <param name="Cliente" value="<%= Cliente_Id %>" />
```

But I got a new error,

```
ClassFormatError: Incompatible magic value 218774561 in class files FormMain
```

In details of this error, appears the following stack

```
plugin2manager.parentwindowDispose
Exception in thread "thread applet-com.griaule.fingerprintsdk.appletsample.FormMain-1" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.awt.EventQueue.isDispatchThread(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.uitoolkit.impl.awt.AWTAppletAdapter.runOnEDT(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.uitoolkit.impl.awt.AWTAppletAdapter.doClearAppletArea(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2Manager$AppletExecutionRunnable.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
plugin2manager.parentwindowDispose
```

**UPDATE**

The `OnClick` event of the button on my web application, open a pop up calling the `Applet.aspx` page.

**Applet.ASPX code**

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Applet.aspx.cs" Inherits="Ui.San.Chaves.Applet" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script src="../Java/jquery-1.6.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="../Java/jquery.base64.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="../Java/preloadCssImages.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="../Java/jquery-1.4.4.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <applet code="com.griaule.fingerprintsdk.appletsample.FormMain" 
        archive="http://www.netimoveis.com/SignedFingerprintSDKJava.jar, http://www.netimoveis.com/SignedFingerprintSDKJavaAppletSample.jar, http://www.netimoveis.com/sqljdbc4.jar"
        height="550" width="550">
        <param name="Cliente" value="<%= Cliente_Id %>" />
    </applet>
</body>
</html>
```

Someone can Help me ? I need to call the applet in the load of my web application and when my user click on my button in the same web application.

Maybe a way t unload the applet .dll of the application and load in the another pop up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ..the applet will open in a pop up..

Open the applet free-floating using [Java Web Start](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/java-web-start/info).  The applet will have a new JVM for each launch, and the DLL problem will disappear.  As a bonus, JWS will allow you to partition the download of natives for OS X & *nix.

---

As far as the`ClassFormatError` goes, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10327211/418556), which suggests that value adds up to `CR`, `LF`, `<` and `!`.  Such characters might be typical of the start of a server generated '404' page.

Comment: I saw in this [article](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/applet-migration-139512.html) that `A Java Web Start application does not run within the web browser. So if your applet has any dependency on the browser (for example, Java to JavaScript / JavaScript to Java communications by means of the browser), the communication code will no longer work.` Well, I need work with a javascript and applet

Comment: As an aside, that is a very old article.  Since Java 1.6 & the 'next generation' plug-in, applets can remain embedded in a web page, while being deployed using JWS.  See the info. page on the applet element for more details.

Comment: I update my question putting the aspx ode of the `Applet.aspx`, page that call my Java Applet. Do you think that I need to call. This is the same code that I'm using in the web application withou open the pop up.