# Magic value error when I run my applet

Tags: java

I create an Applet and I generate the `jar` file with the following code

**JAR FILE**

```
"c:\arquivos de programas\java\jdk1.7.0_05\bin\jar" cvf C:\Users\lucas\Desktop\AbrirAplicativo3000.jar C:\Users\lucas\workspace\WebcamApplet\bin\com\colorfulwolf\webcamapplet\WebcamApplet.class C:\Users\lucas\workspace\WebcamApplet\bin\com\colorfulwolf\webcamapplet\QRCodeProcessor.class C:\Users\lucas\workspace\WebcamApplet\bin\com\colorfulwolf\webcamapplet\QRCodeListener.class C:\Users\lucas\workspace\WebcamApplet\bin\com\colorfulwolf\webcamapplet\OpenCVWebCam.class C:\Users\lucas\workspace\WebcamApplet\bin\com\colorfulwolf\webcamapplet\CVImageProcessor.class C:\Users\lucas\workspace\WebcamApplet\bin\com\colorfulwolf\webcamapplet\AbstractProcessor.class C:\Users\lucas\workspace\WebcamApplet\bin\com\colorfulwolf\webcamapplet\gui\ImagePanel.class C:\Users\lucas\workspace\WebcamApplet\bin\com\colorfulwolf\webcamapplet\gui\LabelPanel.class C:\Users\lucas\workspace\WebcamApplet\bin\com\colorfulwolf\webcamapplet\gui\LoadingScreen.class C:\Users\lucas\workspace\WebcamApplet\bin\com\google\zxing\StringsResourceTranslator.class C:\Users\lucas\workspace\WebcamApplet\bin\com\google\zxing\client\j2se\BufferedImageLuminanceSource.class C:\Users\lucas\workspace\WebcamApplet\bin\com\google\zxing\client\j2se\CommandLineRunner.class C:\Users\lucas\workspace\WebcamApplet\bin\com\google\zxing\client\j2se\GUIRunner.class C:\Users\lucas\workspace\WebcamApplet\bin\com\google\zxing\client\j2se\ImageConverter.class C:\Users\lucas\workspace\WebcamApplet\bin\com\google\zxing\client\j2se\MatrixToImageWriter.class
```

and I singed the JAR file normally.

I put the JAR file in a visible HTTP (http://www.netimoveis.com/AbrirAplicativo3000.jar)

In my `ASPX` page, I'm calling the `APPLET` following this code

```
<applet code="com.colorfulwolf.webcamapplet.WebcamApplet" 
    archive="http://www.netimoveis.com/AbrirAplicativo3000.jar, http://www.netimoveis.com/AbrirAplicativoAssinado3000.jar"
    height="550" width="550">
</applet>
```

But when I try to run, I got the error

```
Incompatible magic value 218774561 error in applet
```

Someone can help me ?

Comment: What is the URL of the page containing the applet?

Comment: Both jar files should be signed with the same certificate. Make sure this is the case

Comment: Well, I'm developing this, so, are in localhost, and my jar file are in a visible HTTP, and localhost can saw.

Comment: @OmarJackman both was signed with the same certificate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `AbrirAplicativo3000.jar` is not correctly packaged. If you look inside, it has this structure:

```
META-INF/
C:/
  Users/
    lucas/
      workspace/
        WebcamApplet/
           bin/
             com/ --> this is where the jar should start from.
               ...
```

Try using the `-C` option on the `jar` command like this:

```
"c:\arquivos de programas\java\jdk1.7.0_05\bin\jar" cvf C:\Users\lucas\Desktop\AbrirAplicativo3000.jar -C C:\Users\lucas\workspace\WebcamApplet\bin\ .
```

Also it's not the first time that [this magic number](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10327211/1434089) comes up on SO, although it seems more related with a bad URL. However I did download the `jar` with your supplied URL so just try re-packaging it.

Comment: My jar file has to begin in the com/ directory and not in the C:/Users/lucas.... path ?

Comment: Yes, the first level should include your `META-INF` and `com` folders

Comment: I'm trying generate the jar rhough the export tools in Eclipse IDE, but my package with my main clas don't appears when I try to set my Manifest

Comment: I suppose you mean the [JAR File Exporter](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/topic/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.user/reference/ref-export-jar.htm?cp=1_4_9_6). Make sure your main class has a method with the `public static void main(String args[])` signature. However do explain why you need to include a `main(args[])` in an applet. If it's just going to run in a browser/container, you don't need it.

Comment: Strange, I generate a new JAR through JAR File Exporter, but the applet still with error in execution. Incompatible magic value 218774561 error in applet

Comment: Is the `jar` still on the same URL? If it is, it's still packaged incorrectly, now is showing a path all the way to some `C:\Users\lucas\workspace\WebcamApplet\html\` folder filled with jars.

Comment: the jar that I generate with Eclipse IDE using JAR File Exporter, can be downloaded at http://www.netimoveis.com/teste.jar

Comment: OK what you're doing is zipping up the entire project and this will not work with the `<applet>` tag. I see that there's an `html/` folder that holds evertything that you need to publish it, including the `webcamapplet.jar`. Just publish all the contents of this folder **as-is** onto your website.

Comment: `webcamapplet.jar` is a `jar` file that comes in the project when I made the download of him. I tryied to run the `<applet>` with this `webcamapplet.jar`, appears a version without my changes. I tryied with the `teste.jar`, that runs normally (but I put a reference to the another `*.jar` files that need to run the `applet`).

Comment: `<applet code="com.colorfulwolf.webcamapplet.WebcamApplet"        
        archive="http://www.netimoveis.com/teste.jar, http://www.netimoveis.com/core.jar, http://www.netimoveis.com/javacv.jar, http://www.netimoveis.com/javase.jar, http://www.netimoveis.com/jna.jar, http://www.netimoveis.com/customizer.jar, http://www.netimoveis.com/jmf.jar, http://www.netimoveis.com/meidaplayer.jar, http://www.netimoveis.com/multiplayer.jar, http://www.netimoveis.com/sound.jar"
        height="550" width="550">
    </applet>`

Comment: OK it works because the `jar` does include the `com `folder with all the `.class` files. For a cleaner jar, export with the _Export generated class files and resources_ checked.

Comment: Not on executing the applet but definitely when loading the page. `teste.jar` is 2.4MB right now. Just zipping classes will lower it a lot (i.e. `webcamapplet.jar` is only 75KB) .

Answer (score 1):

The magic value error means that the class file doesn't start with the integer 0xCAFEBABE as it should. You probably had a transfer or compression problem.

If you can open the file in an hex editor, you may look for those bytes.